# jqgrid refresh grid button doesn't pass along filters

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filter

when i use jqgrid and enter values on the top toolbar filter or the advanced filter and then click the "refresh grid" button in the footer of the grid, it wipes out the values in the filters.

is this a bug in jqgrid, or is there something that you have to do explicitally for it to keep the state of the toolbar column filters.

is there anyway to get this to work?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you can see in the source code of jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.0.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1803)) the behavior is by design so. The oldest version of jqGrid which I could found is jqGrid 3.5.2 and in the version the grid filters ware also reseted.

If you need another behavior of reload button you can add (using [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons)) your custom button which looks like the original reload button (it cat has "ui-icon-refresh" as the `buttonicon` parameter) and implement another behavior of reloading. For example you can just call `trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}])`.

Another possibility for reloading customization are [beforeRefresh](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) and [afterRefresh](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) events.

Comment: @Oleg - thanks for the feedback.  When you say this is "by design", do you think anyone would ever want to lose the filters on refresh?? Seems like a strange design and more of an oversight . .

Comment: @ooo: I understand what you mean, but in all implementation of jqGrid the "Refresh" button do exact the same: clear the filter and reload the grid. It is almost the same as "Reset" button in the search dialog. If I would implement "Refresh" button I would implement as more as **refreshing from the server** and not as reseting of the filters. In case of `loadonce:true` I would first save the original value of `datatype` ('json' or 'xml') and in the "Refresh" button I would reset the original value of `datatype` and reload the grid without changing of the filters.

Comment: @ooo: The advantage of jqGrid is that you can relatively easy implement the behavior which you need (see my main answer)

Comment: @Oleg - thanks for your additional thoughts.  the tricky part is having to figure out:  1. do i have any toolbar filters, 2. do i have any advanced filters.  3. pass those along with the refresh

Comment: @ooo: You know your requirements better. So you can in case of your situation better decide in which case what have more sense. The `postData.filters` will be shared by different ways of searching/filtering. So at refresh just the current `postData.filters` will be send to the server independent from which source the filter come.

Comment: I just followed your advice (Oleg) and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @boca: You are welcome! I am glad to hear, that I could help you.

Comment: @boca: do you have any code that shows how you solved this problem ??

Comment: @ooo: Here you go 
`$("#items-list").jqGrid({
   etc...
        pager: '#items-pager',
  etc....
    }).navGrid('#items-pager',
    { search: false, edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, searchtext: 'Filter' }, {}, {},{}, {closeAfterSearch: true, closeAfterReset: true, multipleSearch: false }
 ).navButtonAdd("#items-pager", {caption:'', buttonicon: 'ui-icon-refresh', onClickButton: function() {$("#items-list").trigger("reloadGrid");}, position: 'first', title: 'Refresh'}
    ).filterToolbar({ autosearch: true, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false}    );`